# Integrating XML into HTML page for iOS Web App

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xml, geolocation

How do I integrate some XML into one of my HTML pages? I’ve recently got into web development and have only used HTML, CSS and JavaScript to build full stack web apps (Node on the backend). Now I’ve found myself in the middle of an ambitious freelance project for a mobile web app that uses Geolocation and I have zero mobile development experience.

Here is what I am attempting to code in a script tag on my HTML page that (I believe) needs XML modifications:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "config.xml", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

In my config.xml file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <ios>
    <dict>
      <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
      <string>Test NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
      <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
      <string>Test NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
    </dict>
  </ios>
</plist>
```

And my hopes are that the keys "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" and "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" will enable a pop up that asks the user if they'll allow my web app to use location services.

My hunch is that XML is the answer and I just haven't messed with any XML before. I am NOT using Cordova or Phonegap, just JavaScript.

Comment: I think more information is needed to answer this question.  You said your not using cordova or phonegap...just javascript, so what are you coding in exactly? Are you just trying to make a mobile friendly web page?  Without some sort of intermediary like phonegap, cordova, appcelerator, titanium, or nativescript you cannot make an ios app in javascript.

Comment: Yes I am just making a mobile friendly web page, sorry I should have specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml code that you have is only for the publishing apps to the IOS app store, and will not help you make a mobile a mobile friendly website.  Typically, in order to create a mobile friendly site people use a MVVM framework such as bootstrap to help design the app to be mobile responsive.

If you need to access the geolocation of a person visiting your webpage through javascript I would recommend visiting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation.  This will work on all mobile web browsers and desktop web browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am using a CSS framework to help the app be mobile responsive. Also, I am using that exact code you linked to, and it works on desktop browsers and android browsers, but NOT on iOS browsers. At least, iOS won't run the code because of an authorization issue (automatically denies permission to use location services). I was hoping there was XML code or a JS snippet that exists to bypass this authorization issue. For now as a workaround, I am using https://freegeoip.net/ IP API to get geodata that way, but it is not very accurate...

Comment: are you sure its just not turned off on the users phone for ios? https://www.badgermapping.com/knowledgebase/turn-on-geolocation-iphone/

Comment: Yes, I have location services on and Safari is set to "While Using the App." I've done much tinkering with the location services settings to no avail. Thanks for the recommendation however!